# Plugging power into my laptop killed my USB-C-HDMI cables, my monitors, and now it wont charge or boot - how, and why?

Tags: hdmi, lenovo-laptop, usb-c

I've got a bit of perplexing problem, unsure if it's hardware, firmware or software, and not sure how to proceed.

I have a Lenovo Thinkpad  Yoga L13 Gen 2,  booting Ubuntu, Fedora, and Win10 (all fully updated). It's been working fine on its own for some weeks, but yesterday I tried hooking it up to one of my external monitors at home (BenQ EL2870-B) with a USB-C to HDMI cable (SimpleComm DA3120) - both tested hardware I've used with other machine for some months

It seemed fine at first, running  full 4K @ 60Hz, BUT: The instant I plugged in the OEM Lenovo  USB-C charger to the laptop's other USB-C port, suddenly I lost the external display.

Thinking the USB-C_HDMI cable has just died,  I unwittingly tried another one. It didn't work with that same monitor, so I tried a different monitor (another BenQ EL2870-B) and lo, it worked fine...unitl I plugged power back in. At which point again, the  display out was lost again

At this point I got suspicious, as I ALSO noticed:

- After plugging in the second  USB-C HDMI cable (with no charger attached to the laptop initially), the laptop gave an error message on booting saying the 'attached charger was below 65w' - ie. it seemed to detect  this USB-C-HDMI cable as a charging cable for some reason. Once booted up,  plugging and unplugging triggered charging noises/battery notifications.
- Neither of the used USB-C-HDMI cables now  work on ANY machines or monitors any more. Both were totally dead.
- The HDMI ports on those monitors ALSO  no longer worked.
- The HMDI  head of the USB-C-HDMI cable was exceedingly hot.

Suspecting something was amiss, I recorded a third test, this time with a different Cygnett USB-C-HDMI cable and an old LG 27MU67-B monitor, which confirmed it.

The Cygnett USB-C to HDMI worked fine on my HP tablet at first, and fine on the Lenovo L13 too. But the instant I plugged in the USB-C charge cable to the Lenovo, display out failed again, with the cable and  the HDMI port on the monitor subsequently no longer working. I measured ~80 deg C on the HDMI head when I removed it in this case - painfull to the touch).

It was at this point I also noticed something else - the laptop was no longer charging, with any charger, even with no monitor plugged in. Despite doing the usual 'power off and hold the pinhole rest / power button' tricks, the problem did not fix itself. The orange charging light on the side doe not illuminate, the laptop doesnt charge regardless of the USB-C port used, what OS I'm booted in, and the laptop has now fully discharged and will not boot or respond to any stimulus.

All firmware updates were previously installed from Lenovo Support page, BIOS on latest v 1.20.1.18, BUT Intel Management engine is second-from-latest version ( 15.0.23.1706) as the latest installer crashes out and will not install. However,  I can't see anything in the update logs for the latest version that describes this issue, or find any posts anywhere else of similar issues. Both USB C ports previous  charged the laptop fine previously, and the HDMI port also worked fine too.

I suspect this is some sort of hardware fault where power is going somewhere it shouldn't in the USB-C-HDMI chain and doing damage.

My questions are:

- Has anyone ever seen anything similar?
- Does this sound like a firmware misconfiguration or legit hardware fault?
- Does anyone know any way to 'reset' the charging controller so I can at least get the machine booting again?

Thanks very much

Comment: A repair-shop might be more qualified to deal with the problem.

Comment: Offhand, it seems too much power was demanded from the USB-C charger, and there was a hardware issue, as you state. If you're lucky, a fuse blew... and if not, a fix requires replacement of charger circuitry or more. You'd need the *schematic* for your laptop, and the service manual, to start diagnosis. If you don't have that, *and* experience in microelectronics repair, go to a repair shop and get a cost estimate (repairs might be more than a new PC).

Comment: When you say 'too much power demanded from the USB-C charger', I'm not sure how this can be. 

The lenovo charger in question works fine, even now. And the issue presents with, and dmaage was done, to the USB-C-HDMI cable.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Follow-up for whoever comes a-googling down the track:

Lenovo just wound up replacing the whole mainboard. Tech couldn't say what cause it, so I guess we'll never know.

USB-C ports, as I understand it, are firmware-controlled in terms of what pins perform what function for any given connection, based on the handshake when you plug in. Hence why the same port can take 20v in to charge the laptop....or give ~9v (or more/less) out to charge a phone, depending on the PD handshake.

My theory is somehow one of the pins/channels on the two USB-Cs became 'bridged' and thus any time a 20v USB-C charger got plugged in, it was putting 20v up the HDMI cable.

This is just a theory though.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly the same problem with a Lenovo ThinkBook 15 G2.
All worked fine for about a year. Thinkbook was connected with a Kensington USB-C-to-(dual)HDMI adapter. Suddenly both attached display didn't worked anymore on HDMI ports, also not on another PC/laptop. Kensington device also broken. After some troubleshooting conclusion was usb-c port is crashing everything attached to it.

Contact with Lenovo Support in The Netherland and they do not know this problem. An onsite repair is now scheduled for next week.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1183677)